# Sybase SQL Anywhere drop all constraints on a column

Tags: sql, constraints, sqlanywhere, sql-drop

Is it possible in SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 to drop all constrains with a simple and single line of code for a specific column in a table? I know I can get them via sys-tables, but maybe there is some easier way of doing this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't drop multiple constraints with a single statement.

You can use [ALTER TABLE](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/alter-table-statement.html*d5e32616) to drop individual constraints, so `ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER mycolumn DROP CONSTRAINT constraint-name`, but you must execute the statement separately for each constraint you want to drop.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*